# what are the critical hue values for basic colors in opencv

Tags: opencv

I know in OpenCV the hue color has a range of [0, 179] , instead of that has a full set of 360 scales. My question is that what are the critical hue values for the basic six colors, Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue and Magenta? If I have hue value = 7, what color does it correspond to? Red-Yellow? Any weblinks relevant are welcome.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is not for OpenCV ad hoc

Comment: You just divide by 2 to go from the Wikipedia Hue value to the OpenCV value.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks!

Comment: It's purely so that a Hue can be stored in an unsigned byte which can only store 255 max, so the range 0..360 is divided by 2 to come in at 180.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Nice explanation!